# What is the utility of convergent mean/median ratios of probability distributions?

Tags: distributions, mean, median

Exploring mean/median ratios for different distributions led me to this:

[image]

I note the ratio for the **log normal distribution** appears to be the square root of the exponent of 1 i.e. `sqrt(exp(1))`.  The ratio for the **exponential distribution** appears to be the inverse of log 2 i.e. `1/log(2)`.  I can find no references to support these observations - are they right?

How reliable are these ratios for exploring the *'log-normal-ness'* or *'exponential-ness'* of real life distributions, assuming unimodality?

[Code](https://gist.github.com/geotheory/48a649b2b9dbb3d643fc83c6ea8339bf) for this graph.

Comment: "Log distribution" appears to mean lognormal distribution here.

Answer (score 0):

The mean/median ratio can, as you say, be used as a test to assess whether a sample matches a distribution. It is a negative test only: it can say that the sample is different than the distribution. But since it uses only one number, it cannot say that the sample conforms to the distribution. For that, use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Having said that, the mean/median ratio is quite good test of the "long-tailedness" of a distribution of positive numbers. For example, if the mean of wait time for an operation is much bigger than the median, then that means that a minority of patients face very long waits. So for some purposes it is a good statistic to calculate.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris.  Does this ratio have a formal name?  I've seen some refer to _'skewness'_, but that term has a different formal specification.

Comment: I have never seen a name other than mean/median ratio. In general it may have some use for positive variables, but for any variable that can be zero or negative too, it is likely to be problematic, being awkward or ambiguous at best and misleadingly explosive or undefined at worst.